# Is there a Pandas function to create a 7-day moving average from a time-series?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm looking for documentation or a tutorial to create a 7-day moving average from a time-series from Pandas on Python, and visualize it on Matplotlib.

Here's the my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
plt.style.use('seaborn-poster')

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)

df = df.loc['Colima','18-03-2020':'12-08-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')



fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df)
ax.set_ylabel('Casos positivos', fontsize=10)
ax.set_title('Casos positivos acumulados de COVID-19 en Colima (12 de agosto, 2020)', fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
plt.savefig('positivos_registro.png', dpi=500)
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.rolling()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) to calculate moving averages, like this:

```
df.rolling(window=7).mean()
```

`Rolling()` also has an argument `center=True` to have the window calculated centred in the middle. Then it looks 3 days ahead and 3 days back when your window is 7.

The default value is `center=False`. It just takes current day value + 6 day values back when the window is 7.